# Exporting multiple images from R into 1 pdf

Tags: r, image, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

So I have a function that produces 6 graphs into one image and then I have 24 images (all different graphs) from that function. I was wondering if there is a way to have all of those images exported onto one big pdf.

Here is my current code to obtain the graphs:
eemgraphs3<-eem_overview_plot(eem_list3,spp=6,contour=TRUE)

Currently I look at each one individually using this code:
eemgraphs3[2]
eemgraphs3[3]

and so forth until I hit my last data point.

If I could potentially compile them all into one pdf file then I think it would save a lot of time but I do not know how to do that. Thanks for your help!

I have tried these function which I found online to solve this but no results came out of this.

```
pdf("eemgraphs3.pdf")
eemgraphs3[1:24]
dev.off()

install.packages("ply")
library("ply")
pdf("plots.pdf", width = 7, height = 7)
d_ply(eemgraphs3, .(z), failwith(NA, function(x){plot(x$y,main=unique(z))}), .print=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like this:

```
pdf("eemgraphs3.pdf")
par(mfrow = c(4,6))
eemgraphs3[1:24]
dev.off()
```